# Is "do something by date X" inclusive?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, time, dates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does “notified by [date]” include the end date?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/does-notified-by-date-include-the-end-date)

For example, if John says:

> Return it to me by March 24th.

Does it mean that I need to return it to him before 23:59 p.m. March 24th, or
before 23:59 p.m. March 23rd?