# "Please finish this by May 15" — can I still do it today?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, time, dates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does “notified by [date]” include the end date?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/does-notified-by-date-include-the-end-date)

Today is May 15. I have an email in my inbox that says

> Please respond by May 15.

My question is: what does 'by' mean in this context? Is it synonymous to 'no later than'? Or should I have done this on May 14 at the latest?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65531/is-do-something-by-date-x-inclusive http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/does-notified-by-date-include-the-end-date