# "Before date" versus "by date"

Tags: prepositions

Is it incorrect to say "Please do this before Tuesday"?

Is there a difference between that and "Please do this by Tuesday"?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["I will do it by Monday". Does it mean before the beginning or before the end of Monday?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74450/i-will-do-it-by-monday-does-it-mean-before-the-beginning-or-before-the-end-of)

Comment: I object to this question being a duplicate. The linked question addresses the meaning of "by Monday". My question is whether it is correct to say "before Monday" at all, and the meaning of it.

Comment: (The reason I'm asking is that I've been told that "before date" is incorrect and one should say "by date".)

Comment: There have been several other questions of this general type ([What does “by spring 2013” imply?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96097/what-does-by-spring-2013-imply), for example). Note that your question doesn't actually *say* you're wondering whether "before Monday" is valid at all (it *is*, of course). Also note that although both answers here assert an absolute distinction between *by/before*, the reality (as covered by several answers to other questions) is that people frequently *don't* distinguish that precisely, so you may end up being misled.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: it says that in the very first sentence, unless I'm missing something. Regarding the question you link to, again, it doesn't mention "before date" at all, which is exactly the point of this question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a difference, yes.

If you want the job to be ready on Tuesday morning, you would say

> Please do this before Tuesday

If you need it to be done either before or during Tuesday, you would say

> Please do this by Tuesday

In other words, using *by* is inclusive, it means do this on any day up to *and including* the day specified. Using *before* is non inclusive, it means that I expect it to be done when I arrive on Tuesday morning.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to be precise and want it done literally before a certain time, then "before" is the the word to use. If you want it done on or before the specified day or time, the "by" is the right word.

A couple of other expressions that are used (especially in business) are "not later than" (abbreviated NLT)) and "by close of business" (abbreviated COB).

Comment: I've also seen the abbreviation EOD used to mean end of day. For example, "by EOD Tuesday" removes any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Although, by definition, “before Tuesday” actually means “by Monday at the latest”, many people still confuse “by” (up to AND including) and “before” (up to BUT excluding).

So, in reply to the initial question, it is NOT incorrect to say "Please do this before Tuesday"... but if you mean it can still be done on Tuesday, you should definitely rephrase it as "Please do this BY Tuesday".

Also, even if you DO mean “before Tuesday” (i.e. NOT after Monday), you should still consider rephrasing it as “by Monday”, for the sake of clarity, because unaware people might interpret it as “by” even when you really mean “before”.

Just keep in mind that most people don't take the time to check in dictionaries when they try to understand instructions. They just go by instinct, so you might as well make sure there is no possible ambiguity (whatever dictionaries or linguists might say).