# "By time" versus "before time"

Tags: prepositions, time

There is a related question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106167/before-date-versus-by-date), but it's different because that relates to dates whereas I am talking about specific times.

Compare the sentences "The assignment is due *by* 8:00am" and "The assignment is due *before* 8:00am".

My native speaker intuition is that **Before 8:00am** means 7:59:59am is on time, while 8:00:00am and later is late.

Regarding **By 8:00am**, I think here clearly 8:00:00am is OK and 8:01:00am is not. But what about 8:00:01am or 8:00:59am?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, *due by 8 am* means 8 am is not late while *due before 8 am* means 8 am is late. However, from a practical viewpoint, there is essentially no difference because 8 am sharp is just one moment in time.