# Is it grammatically acceptable to write, "by March of 2015"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

The entire sentence would be something like:

> The Center will be established by March of 2015.

I feel confident writing "in March of 2015", but this sentence must convey the fact that at any time up to and including March the Center may be established, but not after.

Comment: See these related links for questions about using "by" a date: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56335/18655
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/106167/18655
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/74450/18655

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer. The part I'm asking about isn't whether "by" means what I think it means. I am interested in whether using "by" with [month] of [year] is grammatically correct.

Comment: I think the answer to the question Edwin links to covers that, and according to that answer your sentence means that the centre will be established at some time up to and including March, but not later. (And yes, it's also grammatical).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by “grammatically correct”; do you?

Comment: Incorrect: The Center will be established at March of 2015. Correct: The Center will be established in March of 2015.

Comment: To be clear though, I'd suggest saying, "The Center will be established by the end of March 2015" otherwise I might interpret "by March" to mean that it'll be open *by the time March 2015 arrives* which means on March 1st I'm going to start asking you why it's not open yet because you said it would be.  For some reason I interpret *by March 24th* to mean by the end of March 24th but *by a month* to mean by the start of that month.