# A correct preposition - account closed due/by/at 12th of May

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I asked my bank to close my account on 12th of May. Also

> I expect the account to be closed [?] 12th of May

. What preposition should be there? I think about by or due.
Also if I want to ask someone a question:
What date was your account closed [missing preposition?]

Comment: related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/does-notified-by-date-include-the-end-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you expect the account to be closed no later than 12 May, then the preposition you need is *by*.

The preposition to use in the question would normally be *on*: ‘On what date was your account closed?’, but you could also say simply ‘When was your account closed?’

Comment: Thank you. Again this problem with preposition, should it not be "What date was your account closed ON? I thought that in questions, the preposition is placed to the end.

Comment: You can put it in either position.

Comment: _As of_ would work too, no?

Comment: _As of_ suggests a continuing state of affairs - and sounds rather bureaucratic.