# Is there a difference in meaning between "I'll be there for 7pm" and "I'll be there at 7pm"?

Tags: differences, prepositions, time

I feel like "for 7pm" is possibly colloquial and perhaps not quite Standard English, but I have heard it a lot. I can't think if there's any difference in meaning between "I'll be there for 7" and "I'll be there at 7". Is there?

Also, where did this form come from? Is it dialectal or colloquial?

I couldn't find a related question on SE or Google, [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126610/a-correct-preposition-account-closed-due-by-at-12th-of-may) is about the difference between "at" and "by".

Comment: It is formal British English.

Comment: That's interesting - I'm British and never registered it had a formal meaning!

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/489274/17956 which was migrated to ELL

Answer (score 2):

'For' means "in good time for". In Britain, formal invitations for dinner used to say "7 for 7.30", meaning that you can arrive from 7 PM onwards, but should definitely arrive before 7.30.

Comment: Compare  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114695/what-does-the-expression-seven-for-seven-thirty-mean,

Comment: That's really interesting, I'm British and I'd never heard of this before!

Comment: @Lou Which part haven't you encountered, "I'll be there for 7:00" or "Be there at 7:00 for 7:30"? I see the latter quite often  in the context  of performance bookings, it means "Be there for set up and sound checks at 7:00 or just after, the performance starts at 7:30"

Comment: If a formal British upper-class dinner invitation says "7 for 7.30", that half-hour period is for "cocktails".

Comment: I've seen it used for all kinds of social events, not just formal ones. The earlier time is when guests can start to arrive, find a drink and/or a seat, and the later time is when the activity itself is scheduled to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think its really more that for is used to describe an event in most cases, such as I'll be there for Christmas, while at is used for a time.

I guess you could use for, for a time, but it sounds odd.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you can use 'for 7' if 7pm is the time of a thing (dinner, event). By using 'for 7' you would indicate that you will be there when the thing starts/happens. Although, possibly, you will be (slightly, or a lot) earlier, because you are making *sure*, are agreeing, that you will be there *at* 7pm.