# Does "I need it by September 30th" mean deadline 24:00 the 30th, or deadline 24:00 29th?

Tags: dates

I need to hand something in "by the 30th" according to instructions. Does that mean that I should hand it in latest the day before (that is the 29th), so the receiver gets it for the work day of the 30th? Or does it mean that I have to send it in so the person gets it before midnight the 30th?

Comment: There is no universal rule of English grammar or semantics which dictates this.  You'll have to ask the person who set the deadline.  All the lawyering in the world won't save you if you don't meet your deadline.

Comment: This is what I'm struggling with most of times. Why they do not use such expressions: "submit e-mail intent for proposal submission **on or before** September 30, 2015, "

Comment: Normally it would mean "in time for it to be acted upon before close of business on Sept 30."  Technically it could mean other things, but anyone who was given the requirement by headquarters and who did not attempt to meet that minimum criterion would be an idiot.

Comment: Also related: *[Is there an AmE/BrE difference whether “by date X” means by the beginning or ending of this date?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225745)* and *[“Before date” versus “by date”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106167)*.

Comment: How irreversible or negotiable are the consequences? Is this homework or a death row pardon?

Comment: If it is due on or before Sept 30, the latest time you should hand it in is first thing in the morning of September 30.  It would be much better to hand it in by noon of September 29.  You don't want to get a reputation as always finishing things at the last minute.

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be turned in on a date later than September 30th.  Feel free to hand it in today, but it will be considered late on October 1st.

Here is an example: In the United States, the due date for tax returns is April 15th, but there is no time of day expressed: http://www.irs.com/articles/2015-deadlines-filing-2014-tax-returns

As such, it is inferred that you must file before the first second of April 16th.  http://www.taxact.com/filing-notice.asp

Comment: Do you have a source which we can inspect to corroborate this assertion?

Comment: Here is an example: In the United States, the due date for tax returns is April 15th, but there is no time of day expressed: http://www.irs.com/articles/2015-deadlines-filing-2014-tax-returns

As such, it is inferred that you must file before the first second of April 16th.  http://www.taxact.com/filing-notice.asp

Comment: Worth editing that into your answer as support.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the UK at least, such an instruction would normally mean "by close of business on September 30th". It's somewhat ambiguous though, and there are certainly clearer ways the request could be worded.